# Replace $number with $number+1 in std::string

Tags: c++, strings

I want to detect `$number` substring in `std::string` and then replace it with `$number + 1`.

For example, the string `Hello$9World$1` should become `Hello$10World$2`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void modifyDollarNumber(std::string &str)
{
    for (size_t i = str.length(); i --> 0 ;)
    {
        if (str[i] == '$')
        {
            size_t j = i + 1;
            while (j < str.length() && isdigit(str[j]))
            {
                ++j;
            }
            size_t len = j - (i + 1);
            if (len)
            {
                std::string sub = str.substr(i + 1, len);
                int num = std::stoi(sub) + 1;
                str.erase(i + 1, len);
                sub = std::to_string(num);
                str.insert(i + 1, sub);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "!$@#$34$1%^&$5*$1$!%$91$12@$3";
    modifyDollarNumber(str);
    std::cout << "Result : " << str << '\n';
}
```

And I can get the result I want which is

```
Result : !$@#$35$2%^&$6*$2$!%$92$13@$4
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

But I want to improve my code so it can be as fast as possible.

How can I simplify `modifyDollarNumber()` function?

Comment: 'fast' is generally within a particular usage; does it need to be fast for lots of small strings like the example, or long strings with many numbers...?

Comment: What's the range of the numbers to be replaced?  Can they be negative?

Comment: @PhilH I will be processing a long string with many $numbers

Comment: @TobySpeight They can’t be negative so they should be larger than 0 and should be integers only.

Comment: Good - I've used an unsigned type in my answer, on that assumption.

Comment: What is the behavior of digits at it's width boundary? Does a number like 99 increment to 100 or reset to 00?

Comment: @Snowhawk There’s no boundary. so 99 should increment to 100.

Comment: Can all values be represented by an unsigned integer (`std::uint16|32|64|128|256`) or is the value unbounded (infinite precision modulo memory)? Be as specific as you can about the values.  Do you want a compiler specific solution (you should provide the name) or do you want a portable solution?

Comment: All values should be represented by an unsigned integer. And I want a portable solution.

Answer (score 4):

Few observations.

I. You don't need to scan the whole string, character-by-character. `str.find('$')` will do it for you (and remember to start the second search, and all subsequent ones, from the last reference detected.)

II. Rather than taking substrings, parsing them, erasing and inserting—why not increment in-place? You know exactly your number span (from the one past '$' to the one past the last digit.) If this string only consists of '9's, insert a single '1' right after '$' and change all nines into zeroes. If there are digits less than nine, increment the rightmost non-nine, and change all the subsequent nines into zeroes, if any, no insertion/erasure required. Proceed with the next search.

III. As @AJNeufeld mentioned, string reconstruction can be done in a separate buffer, though vast testing is needed to decide if this is a faster option.

Comment: thanks for your tips. regarding your second tip, i’m looking for a solution that is easily customizable. for example, it should be easy to change from $(number + 1) to $(number * 2) later.

Answer (score 4):

You've misspelt `std::size_t` throughout, and also `std::isdigit` (which is missing the necessary include of `<cctype>` - note also that passing plain `char` to the character classification functions is risky - cast to `unsigned char` first).

The in-place modification of your string involves copying increasing parts of it multiple times (even when the replacement string is of the same length).  You can avoid that quite simply by using `std::string::replace()` instead of `erase()`+`insert()`:

```
            std::string sub = str.substr(i + 1, len);
            int num = std::stoi(sub) + 1;
            str.replace(i + 1, len, std::to_string(num));
```

This still leaves a lot of copying when the increment adds a digit (9, 99, 999, ...) - I think your test-case should include at least one of each.  To avoid that problem (and to make the usage more intuitive to the caller), it may be better to write a function that returns a copy of the string (so accept it by const reference):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

std::string modifyDollarNumber(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(str.length());
    auto out = std::back_inserter(result);

    auto pos = str.cbegin();
    while (pos != str.cend()) {
        auto dollar_pos = std::find(pos, str.cend(), '$');
        std::copy(pos, dollar_pos, out);
        // no more substitutions?
        if (dollar_pos == str.cend()) { break; }

        // copy the dollar sign
        result += '$';
        pos = dollar_pos + 1;

        // is it followed by a number?
        auto digit_end = std::find_if(pos, str.end(),
                           [](unsigned char c){ return !std::isdigit(c); });
        if (digit_end == pos) { continue; }

        // copy the incremented number
        auto num = std::stoul(std::string{pos, digit_end});
        result.append(std::to_string(num+1));
        pos = digit_end;
    }

    return result;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const std::string str = "$1 $-22 $027 $$ $";
    std::cout << "Result : " << modifyDollarNumber(str) << '\n';
}
```

But if raw speed is more important than readability, you'll need to benchmark with some representative inputs to see which is best for you.

Comment: is it problematic to write simply  ‘size_t’ and ‘isdigit()’ even if it compiles?

Comment: Yes - even though the compiler you're using right now defines these symbols in the global namespace as well as in `std`, there's no guarantee that it will continue to do so, and it almost certainly won't be compilable by at least some people who want to use your code.  Stick to what's guaranteed in the standard, and your code will be much more portable (and therefore useful).

Comment: Of course, if you really want to miss off the `std` prefix, you can `using std::size_t;` early in your function.  But I don't generally recommend that unless you're using it on almost every line.

Answer (score 2):

String manipulation can be slow.  Inserting and deleting characters requires shifting characters in memory, if modifying in place, or allocating and freeing temporaries.

It could be faster to allocate one destination character buffer (`char[]` or `wchar_t[]`), and copy characters into it, performing the translations as required, and then converting into a `std::string` at the end.

The destination buffer would need space for `str.length() + std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), '$')` characters, since `$9` can become `$10`, etc.

Comment: Note that using a fresh string as buffer is approx. as effective.

Comment: I would appreciate a working example if possible.